# Using row.ColumnName on a column with spaces, after a select query generated by C# in WebMatrix

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, webmatrix

I have compiled a string that queries a database like so:

```
stringCompiler = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable";
```

The problem is that some of the columns have spaces in their names (i.e., "City Tag Number").

How can I call this later after I use the db.Query statement. Example:

```
foreach(var row in db.Query(stringCompiler))
{
    var someVariable = row.Column With Spaces;
}
```

Obviously the above code would produce an error.

I could go through each column instead of using ' * ', all the while assigning aliases to all of the column names with spaces in them. Example:

```
stringCompiler = "SELECT \"City Tag Number\" AS CityTagNumber, ...";
```

But there are a lot of column names in this table and I am assuming there is a better way, and that I just can't find it (I promise, I've looked).

Any help is much appreciated.

----------------EDIT------------------------

I should've specified that I was using SqlServer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sql text passed to the DB engine, usually (but it depends on the actual db) you use square brackets (SqlServer, Access) or backticks (mysql)

```
 stringCompiler = "SELECT [City Tag Number] AS CityTagNumber, ...";

 stringCompiler = "SELECT `City Tag Number` AS CityTagNumber, ...";
```

while in code (assuming row is a DataRow) you use the name of the column as string

```
foreach(var row in db.Query(stringCompiler))
{
    var someVariable = row["City Tag Number"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I swear, I tried everything but the square brackets. I am trying that now. If successful, I will be back to accept. If not, I will be back with more questions :)  Also, sry, I should've specified that I was using SqlServer.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks! Actually, I don't think I ever would've guessed that, because it's not row.["City Tag Number"], it's just row["City Tag Number"] (removing the dot between the variable name and the column name). I don't get that because otherwise it would be row.CityTagNumber (if the column name had no spaces). Either way, it works! Thanks!

Comment: Also, I've always used quotations in my select statement for columns with spaces in SqlServer like so:  "City Tag Number". Of course when compiling the string in C# this method requires the backslash ('\') escape character like so: selectQueryString = "SELECT \"City Tag Number\" FROM TableName"  But if square brackets work too, I'd say that's easier, as it will quit tricking the autocomplete into thinking I am done with the string. Thanks for that, as well!

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer by @Steve is a great answer, here's a suggestion that might make your life a bit easier.  Go into SQL Server and define a view into the table of interest:

```
SELECT [City Tag Number] AS CityTagNumber, [Second Field Name] AS SecondFieldName...
FROM  YourTable
```

Then in your code, use the view instead of directly referencing the table.  That way, you only have to do it once, and will make your code more readable and shorter since in the code you won't need all the AS aliases.  The view works exactly as if you were going directly to the table.  I use this technique and if the table name is YourTable, i call the view vYourTable.

Comment: Thanks! I like this. I'll have to try it! Any advice you can give me on how to do this, considering I use WebMatrix (Sql Server Compact)? I've never done this before.

Comment: i think the professionals would use SQL Server Management Studio to open the Compact database and manage it there.  An alternate is to run Microsoft Access in what i think of as direct (or native) mode.  You can use Access to create a view.  If you've used Access before, Access normally calls these queries, but they are known in the database world as views.