# Column does not belong to table - grab data by column alias

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am executing a long and convoluted stored procedure... the code works and outputs a table successfully; so that's not the problem. The last column is a mess of a calculation and uses the 'AS' clause to name itself "FTE" and it does so successfully when I execute it in SSMS.

However, when I try to grab the data from that column in my ASP.NET C# code it gives me the error

```
"Column 'FTE' does not belong to table dbo.Employees."
System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

I'm adding the data to my model like so, which is working for all the other columns

```
model.fte = Double.Parse(row["FTE"].ToString());
```

Am I not allowed to grab rows based on an alias name because it's a calculation? If I can't do it by the column alias, then how would I get that information??? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979184/using-row-columnname-on-a-column-with-spaces-after-a-select-query-generated-by

Comment: Thanks for trying to help... but I am executing a stored procedure. Not querying a table. The solution(s) in the provided link aren't helping.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot... I was calling the wrong SP which just happened to have the same exact column names... except for that one that was failing. I deserve 100 down votes...